# iOS - Background processes and UI update

Tags: ios, background, nsthread, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

the question is simple : my app control if there is an update every time it starts. If there is an update a popup will be shown with a Yes or No choose. When user tap Yes 4 methods start. These methods download xml file and upload CoreData. This is the code of the alert :

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if (buttonIndex==1) {
        [self showActivityViewer];
        [self downloadControlAndUpdatePoi];
        [self downloadControlAndUpdateItinerari];
        [self downloadControlAndUpdateArtisti];
        [self downloadControlAndUpdateEventi];
        [self hideActivityViewer];
        NSLog(@"AGGIORNA");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"NON AGGIORNARE");
        return;
    }
}
```

But there is a problem : when user tap Yes the alert doesn't disappear and remain on screen until all methods are finished. So i try this other code :

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if (buttonIndex==1) {
        [self showActivityViewer];
        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startDownloads) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
        [self hideActivityViewer];
        NSLog(@"AGGIORNA");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"NON AGGIORNARE");
        return;
    }
}

-(void)startDownloads {
    NSInvocationOperation *opPoi=[[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(downloadControlAndUpdatePoi) object:nil];
    NSInvocationOperation *opItinerari=[[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(downloadControlAndUpdateItinerari) object:nil];
    NSInvocationOperation *opArtisti=[[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(downloadControlAndUpdateArtisti) object:nil];
    NSInvocationOperation *opEventi=[[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(downloadControlAndUpdateEventi) object:nil];
    NSArray *operations=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:opPoi,opItinerari,opArtisti,opEventi, nil];
    NSOperationQueue *queue=[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [queue addOperations:operations waitUntilFinished:YES];
    [queue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];

}
```

There is a problem even here : i tap start, but the activity viewer doesn't appear. The alert disappear and the thread start and run the 4 methods one after another.

I need the processes run in background, just like happened with my 2nd code, but i need even my showActityViewer method will be run and show the spinner.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First things first. You don't need to start 4 operations, since you are already in a secondary thread and do not need that the 4 operations be executed in parallel. You could simply do:

```
-(void)startDownloads {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];  
    [self downloadControlAndUpdatePoi];
    [self downloadControlAndUpdateItinerari];
    [self downloadControlAndUpdateArtisti];
    [self downloadControlAndUpdateEventi];
    [pool release];
}
```

Above all, you need define an autorelease pool in `startDownloads` if you use `autorelease` in the `downloadControl*` methods, otherwise I suspect you will have leaks.

As to why the activity indicator does not show up, it depends on the fact that you are calling:

```
    [self hideActivityViewer];
```

immediately after detach. So, you are showing it and removing it, before event the UI has got the time to update itself. Remove that line from there and rewrite `startDownloads` like this:

```
-(void)startDownloads {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];  
    [self downloadControlAndUpdatePoi];
    [self downloadControlAndUpdateItinerari];
    [self downloadControlAndUpdateArtisti];
    [self downloadControlAndUpdateEventi];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(hideActivityViewer) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];  

    [pool release];
}
```

Here notice that I am calling into the main thread to `hideActivityViewer` because only the main thread can safely use `UIKit`.
EDIT:

I did not know that you were using Core Data in the download methods...

Have a look at [Concurrency with Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html). You will need to tweak a bit your code by at least using a separate managed object context for your secondary thread (I don't know if it is feasible for you to create the moc there).

Also have a look at [this tutorial from Cocoa is my Girlfriend](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/05/04/core-data-and-threads-without-the-headache/).

As an alternative to all that, you could consider doing:

```
if (buttonIndex==1) {
    [self showActivityViewer];
    [self performSelector:@selector(startDownloads) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
    NSLog(@"AGGIORNA");
} else {
    NSLog(@"NON AGGIORNARE");
    return;
}
```

with:

```
-(void)startDownloads {
    [self downloadControlAndUpdatePoi];
    [self downloadControlAndUpdateItinerari];
    [self downloadControlAndUpdateArtisti];
    [self downloadControlAndUpdateEventi];
    [self hideActivityViewer];  
}
```

This does not use threads at all, but I am not sure that the activity viewer will show without any glitch. One more level of hack, if needed, and you could specify a delay in

```
[self performSelector:@selector(startDownloads) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
```

Comment: but how have i to call startDownloads? With NSThread detach or [self startDownloads] after user tap Yes?

Comment: Sorry, with detachThread; you are doing this correctly. the only point is, in startDownloads you do not need more async operations, they can just be sequential.

Comment: Seems it is all ok, but one problem, big problem, occurred : my downloadAndControl* methods work with CoreData and with this solution i have an NSInternalInconsistencyException with method save of CoreData.

Comment: Good, solved all!!! The methods that use CoreData must be run by the main thread, so i use performSelectorOnMainThread to run these methods. Thanks thanks thanks to sergio for his awesome answer! :)